# Concat values from an API Response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm getting info from an API, and one of the returned values is a list of coupons. Per example:

```
[{"Consecutive":11,"Code":"E5ZQHZ","Cvv":"GNH","IdCoupon":77236},{"Consecutive":12,"Code":"WM96FY","Cvv":"NGE","IdCoupon":77237}]
```

What I need to do is concatenate the values from Consecutive, Code, Cvv and show them like a list (something like this):

```
<ul>
<li>'Code'/'cvv'/'consecutive'</li>
<li>'Code'/'cvv'/'consecutive'</li>
</ul>
```

How can I do that? I'm using Javascript and AngularJs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `ng-repeat` in your `ul` like so:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.data = [{
    "Consecutive": 11,
    "Code": "E5ZQHZ",
    "Cvv": "GNH",
    "IdCoupon": 77236
  }, {
    "Consecutive": 12,
    "Code": "WM96FY",
    "Cvv": "NGE",
    "IdCoupon": 77237
  }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <ul ng-repeat="d in data">
  <li>{{d.Code}} / {{d.Cvv}} / {{d.Consecutive}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

There are other possible solutions but this should set you up nicely.